# Visual Studio Annotate changing line number in view

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, tfs, annotate

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 with VB.NET, in a 4.0 project, with Team Foundation Server.  When  I annotate, not only do I not see line numbers (which is apparently an unfixed bug with VS 2010 - http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/553557/when-invoking-tfs-annotate-in-visual-studio-there-are-no-line-numbers-shown) but annotate also advances the screen 10-15 lines, which makes it difficult to find the code I was actually attempting to Annotate.

Has anyone run into this before?  Any chance you've figured out a fix for it?  Even knowing I'm not alone would be nice.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've run into this also, but keep in mind the following:

1. If you Annotate from Solution Explorer, it'll start you at the top of the file.
2. If you Annotate from the file with the right-click menu, it'll start from where your cursor is located when you go to annotate.
3. If you Annotate from the file with the File -> Source Control -> Annotate, it'll start from the top of the file again.

To find particular code that I want annotated I do one of two things:

1. Annotate with the right-click menu on the line of interest. Close the file when I'm done, and repeat as necessary.
2. Liberal use of `Ctrl+F`

Hopefully, the VS team will fix this next time around.

Comment: Yeah, I was missing #2 here - going to my cursor location.  I'll just try to always right click on the first line to stay as close as possible to the behavior I actually want.  Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Small workaround: you can use the shortcut Ctrl+G ("Go To Line") to go to a specific line...

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party for VS 2010 but according to the documentation (and it does work) you can also hover over the annotations and it lists the line numbers the annotation covers.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385979(v=vs.100).aspx